# Отступ между Title и гамбургером в Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Всем доброго времени суток! Возник вопрос, почему в `ActionBar` появился такой большой отступ между `Title` и `гамбургером`? У меня так:
[image: Мой Toolbar]
А так должно быть:
[image: Другой Toolbar]
Изображение гамбургера взял из Drawable, но оно квадратное. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Появление отступа обусловлено material design guidelines.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данный отступ появляется начиная с **support library v24**. Для того что бы его убрать добавьте в ваш тулбар атрибут app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp":

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...
    app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp">

    ...    
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: @AlphaWinner да не за что.